# Visual studio code. Горячие клавиши

Tags: visual-studio-code

Навесил hotkey `alt+shift+c` на `New c# class`, как в visual studio. При нажатии комбинации появляется поле ввода для имени класса. Ввожу имя - файл класса не создается. Через контекстное меню в проводнике всё нормально. Как сделать чтобы работало?